# Node how to add required validation and custom message

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating a simple API for user registration not saving anything just console it. What I need to know is how can I add the required validation. I have 4 fields user email, userPassword, userName, user number. I have successfully added validation on email and password but if I didn't send name and number through postman it's also working I need to add validation to name and number so if I didn't pass name and number in API it will say name and number required.

My code

```
app.post('/createUser',
    body('userEmail').isEmail(),
    body('userPassword').isLength({ min: 5, }), function (req, res) {

        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }

        console.log(req.body);
        res.status(200).send('User successfully created');
    });
```

Also if the email is not validated its showing this error

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "value": "umaiz",
            "msg": "Invalid value",
            "param": "userEmail",
            "location": "body"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to change its structure like

```
{'success': false, 'msg':'Email address is not valid.'}
```

Because as the previous message it's too hard for me to handle that error so I can just show the message on which value the error is showing.

Answer (score 0):

1st: use `exists` method:
`body('name', 'some error msg').exists()`

2nd: Add a parser before returning the error in `res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });`

Parser could be looks like:

```
function parse(errors) {
 return {
  success: false,
  msg: errors.map( (error) => `${error.msg}: ${error.param}` )
 }
}
// Result will be in format: {success: boolean, msg: string[]}
```